How to read comma, separated string into a list with pandas and store in in neo4j
I have an Excel sheet and one Cell of it could contain a comma-separated string, e.g.
foo, bar, baz.
I want to read it with pandas and store it as a list which then should be stored in a neo4j db.
But regardless of what i try, i always get an string like that:
"['foo', 'bar', 'baz']" but i need `["foo", "bar", "baz"]
So, the read_excel gets just some converters for the other colums. Setting list here results in an error, that lists are unhashable.
dtypes won't accept list as well :-/
Any Idea how to proceed here?
I've also tried to use this solution somehow, but without any success:
How to read a list from an excel cell

@mozway as requested, the to_dict('tight') output:
{'index': [0, 1, 2], 'columns': ['name', 'alternative_names', 'description'], 'data': [['test_service1', 'ts1, xs1, zs1', 'This is a description'], ['test_service2', 'ts2', 'This is a description'], ['test_service3', 'ts3', 'This is a description']], 'index_names': [None], 'column_names': [None]}


Do you have a comma separated string or a string representation of a list?

Can you please provide the output of pd.read_excel(your_file).to_dict('tight') as [edit] to your question?

As a workaround, you could send strings like "['foo', 'bar', 'baz']" as-is to a neo4j Cypher query, and use Cypher to convert it to a list of strings. For example, if you pass such "raw" strings to your Cypher query in a $raw parameter:
WITH SPLIT(REPLACE(SUBSTRING($raw, 1, SIZE($raw)-2), "'", ""), ', ') AS my_list
...


Thank you! In my case, just the SPLIT($raw, ', ')did the Job :)
